# Referencing a .NET Standard project from full .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have a .net standard 1.4 project which I am referencing via project reference from a .net 4.6.1 project.

When I run I get the following message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I can work around this by referencing the nuget package for System.Threading.Thread version 4.3.0. But for some reason this is actually version 4.0.1.0 which then means I need a binding redirect.

Adding a binding redirect gets me past this issue and onto the next one. Which is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

Do I need to manually add packages (and potentially binding redirects) for all of the dependencies of my .net standard packages? This doesn't seem to be what was sold. Whats the point of .net standard if I have to ship with all the assemblies it needs even through these are already included in the GAC in the .net framework I am targeting. I can't see how this can be sold as .net standard 1.4 is compatible with .net 4.6.1 if by compatible you mean as long as you don't use .net 4.6.1 BCL libraries.

The following issue seems to be related https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488
However I have tried the suggested work around there. Which is to add:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

to the .net 4.6.1 project. I tried this and it made no difference.

**UPDATE**
After adding the following to my .net 4.6.1 project:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Legacy2CPSWorkaround" Version="1.0.0">
     <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
 </PackageReference>
```

I now have System.IO.FileSystem in my output directory however its the wrong version. It's 4.0.2.0. Again I can resolve this using an binding redirect but I shouldn't need to.

I don't know where this 4.0.2.0 dll came from because it's not in my packages folder so it can't have come from nuget?

Comment: Have you restored all packages from nuget command window? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Comment: I think my .net standard project is using System.Threading.Thread version 4.0.0.0 (package version 4.0) instead of 4.0.1.0 (package version 4.3) because I am referencing log4net 2.0.8 which has a dependency on 4.0.0.  I would rather fix this in the .net standard lib rather then forcing the consumers to have binding redirects, but don't know how to.

Comment: @Oscar We are using automatic package restore, I've never needed to run restore from the Package Manger Console. get-help NuGet doesn't include a restore. Calling nuget restore from the command line gives: All packages listed in packages.config are already installed. So no doesn't help

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out? I'm having the exact problem with System.IO.FileSystem...

Comment: No, we changed to using multi targeting to work around this problem. If you reference a .net standard assembly via nuget then everything works fine, so you could also publish to a nuget package and use it from there instead of referencing directly.

Comment: Anyone figure anything out yet? Running into the same thing using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting in .NET Standard (referenced from a .NET Framework 4.7.1 wpf app). Results in System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 not found

Comment: Same problem here, also with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` referencing `System.IO.FileSystem` being used in a .NET Framework 4.6.1 class library project.